# How to migrate Movies & TV question to Sci-Fi & Fantasy?

Tags: discussion, migration

When I flag a question the only option for migration is moving it to meta Movies & TV?

How do I move it to another Stack Exchange site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to @waxeagle, sites only get that option after they've graduate to a full site.  We're still in beta so we don't get that.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19958/why-is-batman-all-one-word-and-spider-man-is-separated

Comment: This question was migrated from Movies & TV to Sci-Fi & Fantasy

Comment: @priestvision mods can send it to any site i believe.