# Migrate a question

Tags: support, flagging, migration

I found a [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/100186/quote-that-is-the-point) that I think will be better suited on either [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) or [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/). But when I try to flag the question using **This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network**, All I can see is MTV Stack Exchange Meta site. There's no option to any of other sites in Stack Exchange network.

I found [this](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/545/how-to-migrate-movies-tv-question-to-sci-fi-fantasy) meta post which suggested that being a beta site, that option is still to come. But MTV Stack Exchange is not in beta now.

So, how a normal user (not a moderator), flag a question should be migrated into some other Stack Exchange site other than Its own Meta?

Comment: Uh, disregarding the general problem you're asking about, are you *sure* this question is appropriate for [ell.se] or [elu.se]? I don't have too much experience on these sites (neither do you seem to, though), but this doesn't look remotely on-topic for them. He's not asking what the phrase means, merely for a list of cool scenes it's used in.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson case that may be, I was just trying to suggest that it may be better on those sites. I even provided a comment for OP, providing my insights and suggesting the same thing I tried to do(comment has been deleted now, dunno why or by whom), thing is, this is such rare moment when I see something in this regard on MTV SE, which made me the path for my problem.

Comment: Yes, I deleted that comment, though, as it seemed to be entirely misunderstanding the question and with the suggestion of rather inappropriate sites to ask it on, could be actively harmful.

Comment: meh..I just read it again. maybe I was drunk earlier. anyway, my meta post ($this) is not harmful eh?

Comment: @Visha No, don't worry, the general meta post still makes sense (and I'm currently writing an answer).

Comment: yay! Although AJ has a good answer, it doesnt make sense why display that option if it's unusable

Comment: Though, in fact it might actually be a duplicate of [Where are our migration options?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1641/49)

Answer (score 2):

In general a question belonging on another site is *in itself* not an appropriate close-reason. The primary question you have to ask is, **is it on-topic on *this* site?** Granted, the specific question is indeed not appropriate for our site and has been closed as such. Though, I strongly doubt it's on-topic for either ELL.SE or ELU.SE, though, but let's concentrate on the general problem for now.

Yes, the migration option is directly part of the off-topic close-reason. That is a bit of a design flaw (and quite a legacy relic really), **suggesting that being on-topic elsewhere *could* be a reason for it to be off-topic here. But, it's really not.**

Anyway, so what is that option for and how can you suggest a question for migration. A site ***can* indeed have other sites there in addition to just its own meta site. But these options have to be activated manually** (normally by SE employees called into action by the moderators after corresponding meta discussions deeming it a good idea). However, this only happens when it is necessary and seeing how we migrate about a single question every 3 years to ELU.SE, it's simply not worth it.

The general approach nowadays, especially on such low-frequency sites like us, is to **leave migrations to the moderators** and not have a ton of different sites there, since as described above this can have the disadvantages of encouraging overeager migration close-votes just because a question *might* "fit better" somewhere else. If the question is off-topic *here*, then close it as such with an approrpiate reason. This motivation is also elaborated in the answers to [this related question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1641/49).

*Then* we can think about possibly migrating it to a place where it is on-topic, but we'd rather leave that to the responsibility of the moderators who can very well deal with the work of ~1 migration a month. You can support the moderators and/or the asker in doing so with **helpful comments or even custom moderator flags. However, when doing so, please make sure that it is really appropriate on the other site** (or at least explain in the comment that you're unsure about this). Having the asker reask it on another site only for it to get closed *again* there too is a really unpleaseant experience for everyone involved.

Comment: Rarely seen is right, anyways, this makes clear for me. combining both yours and AJ's answers, I think I get it now. being rare doesn't bring up the necessity to update website itself by SE developers, and will notify moderators if I see something hereafter and wont come here drunk ;)